# iTextSharp: Combining two PDF documents into one

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Forgive me for the bad english..))
There are two PDF-document. Both consist of 197 pages. The first paper of 1-2 pages have links to the other (3-197) page of this document.
We need to combine these two documents into one document of 197 pages:
• 1 - 2 pages - from the first document (with working links, references should be sent to the relevant pages of the new merged document);
• 3-197 pages - from the second document.

```
Doc:= New iTextSharp.text.Document();

ReaderDoc1:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FileName1);

ReaderDoc2:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FileName2);

FStream:=New System.IO.FileStream(OutFileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);

Writer := New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(Doc, FStream);

Doc.Open(); 

Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc1,1));

Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc1,2));

PageCount := ReaderDoc2.NumberOfPages;

For f := 3 To PageCount Do

Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc2, f)); 

End For;
```

As a result, the links are broken. Show you how to keep the links work. 
Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a document A.pdf and a document B.pdf. The links in document A.pdf refer to document B.pdf. Now you want to concatenate A.pdf with B.pdf. If done correctly, you'll end up with a document C.pdf and the links will be preserved. This means that the links imported from document A.pdf will still link to document B.pdf, NOT to the pages imported from B.pdf into C.pdf. The solution to this problem can be found in Chapter 7 of "iText in Action - Second Edition". Below I'm giving you the link to the corresponding Java and C# example.

Java: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=133

C#: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter07&ex=ConcatenateNamedDestinations

The key method is MakeRemoteNamedDestinationsLocal. This will change the remote links that originally pointed from A.pdf to B.pdf into local links inside C.pdf.
This is rather specialist matter. If you don't succeed using these examples, it will be hard explaining what to do on a forum such as Stackoverflow.

Comment: @mkl I answered this question right before going to an ETSI meeting in Berlin. I overlooked PdfCopy in the code; I've corrected my answer.